# How to do testing with Hibernate, H2 using TestNg?

Tags: java, hibernate, testing, integration-testing, testng

What is the proper way of testing DAO layer?

I had `@BeforeMethod` and `@AfterMethod` annotated methods where I created and destroyed `SessionFactory` but it didn't work with multiple tests. Tests were passing if run one by one but not with the maven build when they were run all together so I decided that I should group them using TestNg groups and do `@BeforeGroup` and `@AfterGroup` method where I did the same thing with Hibernate.

So I did something like this:

```
@Test(groups = {"integration"})
public class IntegrationTest
{
    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @BeforeGroups(groups = {"integration"})
    public void setUpHibernate() throws Exception
    {
        // here I configure sessionFactory
        this.sessionFactory = ...
    }

    @AfterGroups(groups = {"integration"})
    public void putItDown() throws Exception
    {
        sessionFactory.close();
    }
}
```

and each of my test extended this class like so

```
@Test(groups = "integration")
public class RateRepositoryHibernateTest  extends IntegrationTest
{
    ...
}
```

and then I noticed that only one extending test had `sessionFactory` set and rest were `null` which is no surprise because that method was supposed to be run once. Now I really don't know what to do.

How to pass data from `@BeforeGroup` method around group test methods?

or

How to do it differently?

or

How to setUp and tearDown `SessionFactory` before and after each test but in a way that I won't get any pesimistic locking exceptions with multiple tests?

--
edit:

Answer explaining how to do it differently is also welcome. I'd like to know what is state of the art in integration testing using TestNg, Hibernate and some in-memory database.

--
edit 2:

stack trace, code of tests below

```
Hibernate: select roomtype_.type_name from ROOM_TYPES roomtype_ where roomtype_.type_name=?
Hibernate: call next value for rates_sequence
Hibernate: call next value for rates_sequence
Hibernate: insert into ROOMS (prefix, housekeepingStatus, availability, maxExtraBeds, standard, maximum, type, name) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into RATES (standardPrice, upchargeExtraPerson, upchargeExtraBed, room, RATE_TYPE, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, 'R', ?)
Hibernate: insert into RATES (standardPrice, upchargeExtraPerson, upchargeExtraBed, room, seasonId, RATE_TYPE, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 'S', ?)
Hibernate: insert into ROOM_TYPES (type_name) values (?)
Hibernate: select roomtype_.type_name from ROOM_TYPES roomtype_ where roomtype_.type_name=?
Hibernate: call next value for rates_sequence
Hibernate: insert into ROOMS (prefix, housekeepingStatus, availability, maxExtraBeds, standard, maximum, type, name) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into RATES (standardPrice, upchargeExtraPerson, upchargeExtraBed, room, RATE_TYPE, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, 'R', ?)
org.hibernate.PessimisticLockException: Timeout trying to lock table ; SQL statement:
insert into RATES (standardPrice, upchargeExtraPerson, upchargeExtraBed, room, RATE_TYPE, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, 'R', ?) [50200-168]
    at org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect$2.convert(H2Dialect.java:317)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at $Proxy13.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2962)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3403)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1210)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:399)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    at net.mklew.hotelms.persistance.RatesPersistanceTest.should_save_rates_and_retrieve_them_with_success(RatesPersistanceTest.java:80)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:673)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:842)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1166)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.runWorkers(TestRunner.java:1178)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:757)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:608)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1158)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1083)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:999)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:203)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:174)
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:111)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Timeout trying to lock table ; SQL statement:
insert into RATES (standardPrice, upchargeExtraPerson, upchargeExtraBed, room, RATE_TYPE, id) values (?, ?, ?, ?, 'R', ?) [50200-168]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:158)
    at org.h2.command.Command.filterConcurrentUpdate(Command.java:276)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:232)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:156)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:142)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Concurrent update in table "PRIMARY_KEY_4": another transaction has updated or deleted the same row [90131-168]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:169)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:146)
    at org.h2.table.RegularTable.addRow(RegularTable.java:146)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.insertRows(Insert.java:124)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Insert.update(Insert.java:84)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:75)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:230)
    ... 54 more
```

code for test:

```
public class RatesPersistanceTest
{

    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    protected HibernateSessionFactory hibernateSessionFactory;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUpHibernate() throws Exception
    {
        Logger logger = mock(Logger.class);
        NativelyConfiguredHibernateSessionFactory hibernateSessionFactory = new
                NativelyConfiguredHibernateSessionFactory(logger);
        this.sessionFactory = hibernateSessionFactory.getSessionFactory();
        this.hibernateSessionFactory = hibernateSessionFactory;
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void putItDown() throws Exception
    {
        sessionFactory.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void should_save_rates_and_retrieve_them_with_success()
    {
        // given
        Money standardPrice = Money.parse("USD 85");
        Money upchargeExtraPerson = Money.parse("USD 80");
        Money upchargeExtraBed = Money.parse("USD 75");
        RoomType roomType = getMeRoomType();
        Room room = getMeRoom(roomType);

        AvailabilityPeriod availabilityPeriod = new AvailabilityPeriod(DateTime.now(), DateTime.now().plusDays(5),
                true);
        Season season = new BasicSeason("season name", availabilityPeriod);
        Rate seasonRate = new SeasonRate(standardPrice, upchargeExtraPerson, upchargeExtraBed, room, season);

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(roomType);
//        session.save(room);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();


        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        //        session.save(roomType);
        session.save(room);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(season);

        session.save(seasonRate);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        // when
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        final List<Rate> list = session.createQuery("from Rate").list();

        // then
        assertThat(list).contains(seasonRate);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

    }

    @Test( expectedExceptions = org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException.class)
    public void season_rate_should_violate_db_constraints_when_saved_without_season()
    {
        // given
        Money standardPrice = Money.parse("USD 85");
        Money upchargeExtraPerson = Money.parse("USD 80");
        Money upchargeExtraBed = Money.parse("USD 75");
        RoomType roomType = getMeRoomType();
        final RoomName roomName = new RoomName("103");

        final Money roomStandardPrice = Money.parse("USD 100");
        final Money roomUpchargeExtraPerson = Money.parse("USD 50");
        final Money roomUpchargeExtraBed = Money.parse("USD 20");
        final RackRate rackRate = new RackRate(roomStandardPrice, roomUpchargeExtraPerson, roomUpchargeExtraBed, null);
        final int maxExtraBeds = 2;
        final Occupancy occupancy = new Occupancy(4, 2);
        Room room = new Room("C", roomName, roomType, HousekeepingStatus.CLEAN, RoomAvailability.AVAILABLE,
                maxExtraBeds, occupancy, standardPrice, upchargeExtraPerson, upchargeExtraBed);


        AvailabilityPeriod availabilityPeriod = new AvailabilityPeriod(DateTime.now(), DateTime.now().plusDays(5),
                true);
        Season season = new BasicSeason("season name", availabilityPeriod);
        Rate seasonRate = new SeasonRate(standardPrice, upchargeExtraPerson, upchargeExtraBed, room, null);

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(room);
        // when
        session.save(seasonRate);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
        // then exception should be thrown
    }

//    @Test
//    public void package_rate_should_violate_db_constraints_when_saved_without_package()
//    {
//
//    }

    private RoomType getMeRoomType()
    {
        final RoomType roomType = new RoomType("cheap" + DateTime.now().toString());
        return roomType;
    }

    private Room getMeRoom(RoomType roomType)
    {
        final RoomName roomName = new RoomName("101001" + DateTime.now().toString());

        final Money standardPrice = Money.parse("USD 100");
        final Money upchargeExtraPerson = Money.parse("USD 50");
        final Money upchargeExtraBed = Money.parse("USD 20");
        final RackRate rackRate = new RackRate(standardPrice, upchargeExtraPerson, upchargeExtraBed, null);
        final int maxExtraBeds = 2;
        final Occupancy occupancy = new Occupancy(4, 2);
        return new Room("C", roomName, roomType, HousekeepingStatus.CLEAN, RoomAvailability.AVAILABLE, maxExtraBeds,
                occupancy, standardPrice, upchargeExtraPerson, upchargeExtraBed);
    }

}
```

hibernate cfg:

```
<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:mem:db1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=0;MVCC=true</property>
        <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="connection.password"/>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCachingRegionFactory</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>

       <!-- skipped mappings -->

    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: When you say before and after each test do you mean each method annotated with @Test or each invocation of the test suite?

Comment: I guess you refer to what I had in the first place (BeforeMethod etc). I mean before each method annotated with Test annotation in each test suite. For me ideal situation would be to have BeforeMethod and AfterMethod so that before each test method in each suite SessionFactory is created and destroyed after test. But if I do that way I'm getting PesimisticLockExceptions and I don't know how I can handle that so I'm looking for some options. Before and After each test method is has a plus that I could save same data  in multiple tests without worries about unique constraints etc.

Comment: Are you getting the java pessimistic lock exception or the hibernate one? http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PessimisticLockException.html vs http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/PessimisticLockException.html

Comment: Hibernate one. I use Hibernate in version 4.1.7 final

Comment: Where are the PessimisticLockExceptions coming from?  @After/BeforeMethod, or inside the test methods?  How are you constructing your SessionFactory, does the instances use the same connection pool?

Comment: @sharakan pardon me for late answer but it was crazy at my job. I added stack trace, code for one test suite and hibernate configuration. Exception comes from inside of test. SessionFactory should be constructed before each test which means that tests use different connection pool (at least I think they are)

Comment: Can you indicate in the code sample what line is line 80, from the exception trace?  Also, do you get that exception if you run ONLY that test, or only when other tests are run as well?

Comment: Here you have test code with line numbers: https://gist.github.com/4641265 Exception is thrown then I run both tests (when I run test suite). When I rerun only failed then it passes. When I run them separately, both pass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My preferred way to test code that uses Hibernate is to use `@BeforeMethod` and `@AfterMethod` test approach.  I don't have any experience with TestNg, but I assume the way it treats those functions is similar to what JUnit3.8.1 does with setUp() and tearDown(), which is what I use.

The key point to me is the idea that [the order of unit test execution shouldn't matter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XUnit#Test_suites).  If you're using `@BeforeGroup` and `@AfterGroup`, then you have the same `SessionFactory` instance, and therefore the same database (in memory or not), and any mutating operations that a test runs on that `SessionFactory` will affect later tests that do read operations.  That may be desired (although the order probably has to be predictable), in which case you're really talking about a single 'integration test', but for your case it sounds like you want the tests to be independent.

Next question is how to do that.  What I do is configure Hibernate to create and connect to in-memory database, run the create schema script on it, and create a SessionFactory, for each test method.

```
@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    String dialectClassName = HSQLDialect.class.getName();
    AnnotationConfiguration config = new AnnotationConfiguration().addAnnotatedClass(DividendScheduleGeneratorImpl.class);

    config.setProperty(Environment.DIALECT, dialectClassName);
    config.setProperty(Environment.DRIVER, jdbcDriver.class.getName());
    config.setProperty(Environment.URL, "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testDB");
    config.setProperty(Environment.USER, "SA");
    config.setProperty(Environment.PASS, "");

    SchemaExport export = new SchemaExport(config);
    export.create(false, true);

    sessions = config.buildSessionFactory();
}

@Override
protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
    sessions.close();
    sessions = null;

    super.tearDown();
}
```

Couple of notes:

1. The schema creation is not all that fast, at least with HSQLDB, which I use.  But as long as you cleanly separate tests that are really testing Hibernate, from tests which use a mockable persistence layer, you should be fine because there won't be that many tests having to work with an actual database.
2. My tests are run single-threaded.  If you're running multi-threaded, you'll need to set the database name so that it's unique for concurrently running tests.

EDIT:

Based on your error stack trace and code, and the fact the tests run independently, I suspect the PessimisticLockExceptions are being caused by the tests running on separate threads against the same database.  Possibly you even have a database-centered deadlock on the RATES table.  Two options for dealing with it are having the tests generate independent databases, or to tell TestNG to run the tests serially.

For the first, you would have to programatically edit the Hibernate connection string from

```
jdbc:h2:mem:db1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=0;MVCC=true
```

to

```
jdbc:h2:mem:<TESTNAME>;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=0;MVCC=true
```

or similar.  In JUnit, I'd use the [TestCase.getName()](http://junit.sourceforge.net/junit3.8.1/javadoc/junit/framework/TestCase.html#getName%28%29), I assume there is a similarly available feature in TestNG.

The alternative is to run serially.  According to the TestNG documentation, serializing the tests should be possible by annotating the class (not the methods) to add @Test(singleThreaded=true)

```
@Test(singleThreaded=true)
public class RatesPersistanceTest
```

That's how it's supposed to work at least, perhaps when you tried it you annotated the method?

Comment: I agree with what you say. This was my first approach but it didn't work, maybe you will help me with that. I posted stack trace so if you could help me out here that would be great. Also you guessed correctly that I want my tests to be independent. I tried grouping them as a workaround for a problem but that created yet another one.  About multithreading - I can't tell if they run concurrently. I remember I tried adding annotation to the whole suite something like @SingleThreaded or something but that didn't help(maybe I did it wrong).

Comment: @Marek Sounds like they're running concurrently.  I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: I tried annotation and it didn't work. I'll try wit db name somehow and report results.

Comment: I hardcoded connection urls for each test but that didn't help. I'm not sure if the problem isn't hibernate logging again. I had issue with that before.

Comment: It looks like I did a crappy job with hardcoding urls because I did that and line after that they were fetched from the file. Luckily I noticed that in testng output, fixed the issue - still in a ugly way - and it worked. Bounty is yours. Now I need just some clean way to setup environment without messing around with hibernate construction service.

Answer (score 0):

I've done something *like* the following trivial example using `AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests`.

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "file:src/test/resources/test-context.xml" })
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
public class TheDAOTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(TheDAOTest.class);

    // N.B. this will be wired AFTER @BeforeTest !!
    @Autowired TheDAO subject;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() {
        final HibernateTemplate ht = subject.getHibernateTemplate();
        ht.deleteAll(subject.listCustomers());
    }

    @Test
    public void noCustomers() {
        final List<CustomerDTO> customers = subject.listCustomers();
        assert customers != null : "listCustomers null result";
        LOG.info("listCustomers: " + customers);
        assert customers.size() == 0 : "Expected zero customers";

        final CustomerDTO customer = subject.findCustomerById(0L);
        assert customer == null : "Unexpected customer found";
    }

    @Test
    public void saveAndFind() {
        final CustomerDTO dto1 = makeDTO("0");
        final CustomerDTO saved = subject.save(dto1);
        assert saved != null ;

        final Long id1 = saved.getId();
        CustomerDTO customer = subject.findCustomerById(id1);
        assert customer != null ;
        assert customer.getId().equals(id1);
        assert customer.getTN().equals(dto1.getTN());

        List<CustomerDTO> customers = subject.listCustomers();
        assert customers != null : "listCustomers null result";
        LOG.info("saveAndFind - listCustomers: " + customers);
        assert customers.size() == 1 : "Expected one customer";

        subject.save(makeDTO("1"));

        customer = subject.findCustomerById(id1);
        assert customer != null ;
        assert customer.getId().equals(id1);

        customers = subject.listCustomers();
        assert customers != null : "listCustomers null result";
        LOG.info("saveAndFind - listCustomers: " + customers);
        assert customers.size() == 2 : "Expected two customers";
   }

   private CustomerDTO makeDTO(final String x) {
       final CustomerDTO dto = new CustomerDTO();
       dto.setX(x);
       return dto;
   }

}
```

For the sake of completeness, the DTO is like something like this:

```
@Entity @Table(name = "customers") public class CustomerDTO {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) private Long id = Long.MIN_VALUE;
    @Column private String X;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(final Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getX() {
        return this.X;
    }
    public void setX(final String x) {
        this.X = x;
    }
    //  etc. 
}
```

And finally, the DAO:

```
@Component
public class TheDAO {

    public List<CustomerDTO> listCustomers() {
        return getHibernateTemplate().loadAll(CustomerDTO.class);
    }

    public CustomerDTO getCustomer(final Long id) {
        return getHibernateTemplate().get(CustomerDTO.class, id);
    }

    public List<CustomerDTO> listCustomers() {
        return getHibernateTemplate().loadAll(CustomerDTO.class);
    }

    public <T> T save(final T valueObject) {
        getHibernateTemplate().saveOrUpdate(valueObject);
        return valueObject;
    }

    public void setHibernateTemplate(final HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate) {
        TheDAO.hibernateTemplate = hibernateTemplate;
    }

    CustomerDTO findCustomerById(final Long id) {
        return getHibernateTemplate().get(CustomerDTO.class, id);
    }

    HibernateTemplate getHibernateTemplate() {
        return TheDAO.hibernateTemplate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I see some issues with that. 1. It uses Spring and I don't. 2. You showed one test suite and I can handle situation where I have one test suite with all my integration tests and maybe that's the solution but the suite will have few k loc. What I would like to see is where you have many test suites and some shared dependency for each suite is passed around (maybe I should not want that and valid answer will be if someone tells me that).

Comment: Ya, sorry, my solution is very much dependent upon Spring. Also, I didn't show any coupling among tests in a group.